# Cumulative values minus overs

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query that produces the following table with a cumulative column (cumulate)

```
+--+---+--------+------+
|id|qty|cumulate|value |
+--+---+--------+------+
|1 |5  |5       |419.6 |
+--+---+--------+------+
|2 |2  |7       |167.84|
+--+---+--------+------+
|3 |1  |8       |83.92 |
+--+---+--------+------+
|4 |2  |10      |167.84|
+--+---+--------+------+
|5 |1  |11      |83.92 |
+--+---+--------+------+
|6 |5  |16      |419.6 |
+--+---+--------+------+
```

However I need a further attachment to the query that will only select all the rows that cumulate up to 9. In this case the first 4 rows accumulate up to 10 and the first three; 8 .

I need to extract the sum of the total value where the qty is no more and no less than 9.
The rows are in date order (date not shown) and therefor rows cannot be reordered.

How would one achieve this?

EDIT

here is my query (but the results table above is not the same output as what this query would produce):

```
select branch, 
    case  
        when DATEDIFF(MONTH, dateInv, getDate()) between 0 and 6 then '0-6' 
        when DATEDIFF(MONTH, dateInv, getDate()) between 7 and 12 then '7-12'   
        when DATEDIFF(MONTH, dateInv, getDate()) between 13 and 18 then '13-18' 
        when DATEDIFF(MONTH, dateInv, getDate()) between 19 and 24 then '19-24'
        when DATEDIFF(MONTH, dateInv, getDate()) between 25 and 36 then '25-36' 
        when DATEDIFF(MONTH, dateInv, getDate()) > 36 then '>36'    
    end [period]
    ,sum(qty*cost) [costs]
from (
    select branch,qty, dateInv, max(cost)cost, max(soh)[qoh], SUM(qty*cost)[sumqty]
        , sum(qty) over (partition by product order by dateInv desc) [cumulate] 
    from openquery(linkedserver,
    'select   branch,product, soh, cost, dateInv, qty
     from table
     group by branch,product, soh, cost, dateInv, qty
     order by dateInv DESC
    ')
    group by branch,product,qty, dateInv
)t
where cumulate <= qoh
group by branch, dateInv
```

Comment: Do you want the first three rows or the first four?

Comment: Seeing the query would help

Comment: So does it matter which ID's are used?  Say we used ID's 6, 4 and 2 which have respective quantities 5,2, and 2 totaling the 9; but it could also be achieved by using IDs 1,2,3, and 5 with quantities 5,2,1,1 both of those examples generate a cumulative total of 9  is that what you're after?

Comment: This is where I'm confused: "sum of the total value where the qty is no more and no less than 9" that means the total must be EXACTLY 9 if we add up the first 4 the total is 10 so we use the first three and sum PART of the 4th entry?

Comment: Yes -  use the first three and sum PART of the 4th entry

Answer (score 0):

Well from the looks of it each 1 in quantity has a value of 83.92. 9 * 83.92 = 755.28

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your attempts. I managed to solve this problem by using a series of nested queries with "over (partition by)", Row_number and calculations.

Lots of fun !